# TCP MSS not enforced

Tags: tcp, mss

I am doing some TCP related experiment between two virtualbox VMs. On the client side, I sent out a TCP syn packet with the MSS option of 1400 bytes. However, it seems that the server (sender) ignored this option and sent out a packet with very large payload, something like 10000+ bytes.Why didn't the MSS option honored by the server? BTW, the server is a Nginx server.

Below this some PCAP showing the problem. First is the SYN packet with MSS = 1400.
[image]
Second is the payload sent by the server:
[image]
As can be seen that the payload size is 11200.

BTW the MTU on the interface is 1500 bytes.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are doing the capture at the server lookup tcp segmentation offloading (TSO).  If at the client lookup large receive offload (LRO).  I believe both can be turned off with ethtool if you want to see the difference, but generally you should leave them both on.

Comment: I am capturing at the receiver side, and the lro is already turned off.
ethtool -k enp0s8 | grep large
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]

Comment: Ah, it is gro. I have to turn that off. Thanks.

Comment: Note that TSO/LRO are optimizations within the kernel that happen at such a low level that a network capture will show the large frames.  What is actually on the wire, however, will honor MSS.  So the only effect of turning them off it to see smaller frames in a network capture and reduce the performance of your nginx.

Answer (score 0):

By discussion with Jim.The issue this LRO/GRO. Please turn that off if we want to see the packets as they appears on the wire.